Netcdf file exploration on the command line
Given a netcdf file with a variable with a dimension, can I use some command line tool to find the indices of the dimension where the variable satisfies some condition, eg equals a particular value or satisfies some inequalities?
For example, given
netcdf geo_coordinates {
dimensions:
    rows = 26 ;
    columns = 27 ;
variables:
    int latitude(rows, columns) ;
    int longitude(rows, columns) ;
}

Can I use some command line tool to return an array of pairs of values for rows and columns where latitude is a certain value or satisfies some inequality or set of inequalities? Output would be an array of pairs of rows, columns
I certainly could write code to do this but don't want to reinvent the wheel
While I have a very particular task at hand, the question is essentially file exploration on the command line, so I have asked it in as general a way as possible
